# Exporting methods of nested classes from dll

Tags: c++, nested-class, dllexport

I have *.cpp and *.hpp files with class having the following structure:

### first hpp file

```
class FirstClass{
public:
    FirstClass();
    ~FirstClass();

    SHORT FirstMethod(arguments ...);
    void  SecondMethod(arguments ...);
    ULONG thirdMethod(arguments ...);
    ....
    void lastMethod();
private:
    std::list<std::string> STLStringList;
};
```

I try to export my main class from DLL and use functions from my nested class (class FirstClass). I create main class having the following structure:

## main class

```
#ifdef MAINCLASSDLL_EXPORTS
#define MAINCLASS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MAINCLASS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// This class is exported from the MainClassDll.dll
class MAINCLASS_API MainClassDll{
public:
    MainClassDll();
    // Methods from class FirstClass
    virtual SHORT FirstMethod(arguments ...);
    virtual void  SecondMethod(arguments ...);
    virtual ULONG thirdMethod(arguments ...);
    ....
    virtual void lastMethod();
};


extern "C"{
    MAINCLASSDLL_API MainClassDll *CreateObject();
    MAINCLASSDLL_API void DestroyObject(MainClassDll *pobjMainClassDll );
}
```

Methods form FirstClass use private STLStringList and all methods must use the same object of FisrtClass. I try to create method which export pointer to object of FirstClass but when I try to use this methods my program crashes. I can't change struct of FirstClass.
It is possibly to create DLL project to used methods from my nested class without interfering with nested class??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you want most of the `FistClass` class private within the DLL, as a sort of internal structure, but still export some functions from it. This could be solved with inheritance: You make the public `MainClassDLL` an abstract base class, and then have `FirstClass` inherit from `MainClassDLL`.

Something like

```
struct MainClassDLL
{
    virtual SHORT FirstMethod(arguments ...) = 0;
    virtual void  SecondMethod(arguments ...) = 0;
    virtual ULONG thirdMethod(arguments ...) = 0;
    ....
    virtual void lastMethod() = 0;

    virtual ~MainClassDLL() {}
};

// In private header file
class FirstClass : MainClassDLL
{
public:
    FirstClass();
    virtual ~FirstClass();

    SHORT FirstMethod(arguments ...);
    void  SecondMethod(arguments ...);
    ULONG thirdMethod(arguments ...);
    ....
    void lastMethod();

private:
    // Private data
};
```

Then the `CreateObject` function just creates an instance of `FirstClass` and returns it as a pointer to `MainClassDLL`.

Comment: I think this is a canonical answer and correct, but I the OP mentioned that `FirstClass` can't change (although it is unclear if it was just the content or can't change at all). I wonder if maybe a pimpl solution would be better here?